# How to call Servlet from html inside subfolders of webcontent?

Tags: jsp, servlets, web-applications

I wish to call servlet using form action in `HTML`.
I have many html and jsp so i separated all by using folder. I kept that folder inside webcontent of my project.
But, I can't able to access servlet.

My file structure:

Servlet is at

```
./../../src/servletPackage/Servlet.java
```

`HTML` is at

```
/../../Webcontent/NewFolder/first.html
```

Comment: And how is your servlet mapped in the `web.xml`?

Comment: Is servlet mapping in web.xml must? I used annotations.. How can i map it ..? Please explain

Comment: Then show your code. How could people help you if you don't provide enough information?

Comment: I do nothing inside web.xml.. But, this file and servlet calling run when i put html page just in webcontent. Not by folders